# Combine 2 Booking Tables

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Simple question - customer has asked to combine 2 sets of booking data.

The 2 sets are from different types of bookings:

BookingA Table Fields:

- Booking_Arr_Date
- Booking_Date
- Booking_Status
- BookingEntryTime
- BookingExitTime
- BookingLastUpdated
- CarParkCode
- CarParkGross
- CarParkID
- ChannelID
- ChannelName
- Cust_Email*
- DateImported
- Departure
- Destination*
- duration
- leadtime
- ProductCode
- ProductID
- Purpose
- SubStatus
- CustomerOrigin

BookingB Table Fields:

- Email*
- Destination*
- Arriving-Departing

CombinedBooking Table Fields:

- Arriving-Departing
- Booking_Arr_Date
- Booking_Date
- Booking_Status
- BookingEntryTime
- BookingExitTime
- BookingLastUpdated
- CarParkCode
- CarParkGross
- CarParkID
- ChannelID
- ChannelName
- Cust_Email
- DateImported
- Departure
- Destination
- duration
- leadtime
- ProductCode
- ProductID
- Purpose
- SubStatus
- CustomerOrigin

The * Shows common fields, although the email fields have different names

The CombinedBooking table should simply include all the data from the BookingA and BookingB tables. The data doesn't need to be combined or altered in any way.

If the tables contained the same fields a UNION would work a treat, but as the tables include different fields and we want them all this doesn't appear an option AFAIK.

The following query will return the combined data with the correct number of rows:

```
Select [Arriving-Departing], Booking_Arr_Date, Booking_Date, Booking_Status, BookingEntryTime, BookingExitTime, BookingLastUpdated, CarParkCode, CarParkGross, CarParkID, ChannelID, ChannelName, Cust_Email, DateImported, Departure, b.Destination, duration, leadtime, ProductCode, ProductID, Purpose, SubStatus, CustomerOrigin

FROM [BookingA] as a

FULL OUTER JOIN [BookingB] as b

ON a.Cust_Email = b.Email
```

Note: the 'ON a.Cust_Email = b.Email' part bothers me, it doesn't appear to interfere with the query however I don't actually want to include it, but can't validate/run the SQL without it.

However, the BookingB common fields data (Email, Destination) is not included in the result - so the BookingB Table data only includes the Arriving-Departing data.

How can I include the BookingB common fields data (Email, Destination) in the data?

I may have the wrong approach here, always happy to learn where abouts on StupidMountain I am currently!

Thanks for reading and your help as always StackExchangers!

Matt

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're wanting an *inner* join, not outer.  You can also utilize the aliases to return the field values from the proper data extensions:

```sql
select
  b.[Arriving-Departing]
, a.Booking_Arr_Date
, a.Booking_Date
, a.Booking_Status
, a.BookingEntryTime
, a.BookingExitTime  
, a.BookingLastUpdated
, a.CarParkCode
, a.CarParkGross
, a.CarParkID
, a.ChannelID
, a.ChannelName
, a.Cust_Email
, a.DateImported
, a.Departure
, a.Destination
, a.duration
, a.leadtime
, a.ProductCode
, a.ProductID
, a.Purpose
, a.SubStatus
, a.CustomerOrigin
from BookingA a
inner join BookingB b on b.email = a.cust_email and b.destination = a.destination
```

[**Jeff Atwood's visual on JOINs**](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) is a really good reference, IMO.

**EDIT**:  If you just want to smash both sets of rows together, then you can just use a UNION ALL, making sure the column names match.

```sql
select
  b.[Arriving-Departing]
, b.destination
, b.email
, null Booking_Arr_Date
, null Booking_Date
, null Booking_Status
, null BookingEntryTime
, null BookingExitTime  
, null BookingLastUpdated
, null CarParkCode
, null CarParkGross
, null CarParkID
, null ChannelID
, null ChannelName
, null CustomerOrigin
, null DateImported
, null Departure
, null duration
, null leadtime
, null ProductCode
, null ProductID
, null Purpose
, null SubStatus
from BookingB b

union all 

select
  null [Arriving-Departing]
, a.Destination
, a.Cust_Email email
, a.Booking_Arr_Date
, a.Booking_Date
, a.Booking_Status
, a.BookingEntryTime
, a.BookingExitTime  
, a.BookingLastUpdated
, a.CarParkCode
, a.CarParkGross
, a.CarParkID
, a.ChannelID
, a.ChannelName
, a.CustomerOrigin
, a.DateImported
, a.Departure
, a.duration
, a.leadtime
, a.ProductCode
, a.ProductID
, a.Purpose
, a.SubStatus
from BookingA a
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for coming back on this one - I think I've not explained it very well. The client wants 100% of both tables, and no matching required. So if table A has 50 entries and Table B has 50 entries the result would be 100 rows, with all rows looking identical to how they were in the original tables.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Absolute legend, thank you Adam!